# How much time passes between the end of the first cour and the start of the second cour?

Tags: active-raid

The start of *Active Raid 2nd* ("episode 13", so to speak) clearly takes place some time after the end of *Active Raid* ("episode 12") - Sena has joined a garbage company (and reports being out of practice); Asami has been transferred to Unit 9; Inagi Koutarou is now the governor of Tokyo; and so forth.

This puts a lower bound of probably around a few months on the timeskip. Do we have any better idea as to how long passed between the two cours? (This seems like the sort of thing that'd be mentioned in promotional materials or something.)